# kill process in task manager using c#

Tags: c#, wpf

how can I kill process or close whole application for my WPF application using c#?

Comment: *Your* application (that is currently hosting your code), a process you *spawned*, or an arbitrary process running on Windows?

Comment: that is currently hosting my code :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using WinForms? Assuming you want to close it via code (and not from the window's close button), you could use [Application.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9398s20y.aspx). If you want to kill a process, then you can use the [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) method.

Edit - Since you're using WPF, you can use the [Application.Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can Kill a process using [Process.Kill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx), and close it nicely using 
[Process.CloseMainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx).

To find the process, use methods of the Process class such as [Process.GetProcessById](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid.aspx) or  [Process.GetProcessesByName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname.aspx).

However, to kill another process (depending on the process), you may need elevated permissions.  You'll need to start your executable with these in order for this to work, in that case.

You can use [Environment.Exit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx) to close your own process, or [Environment.FailFast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.failfast.aspx) to kill it quickly.

---

Edit:

Since you're using WPF, you can also use [Application.Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdown.aspx) to close your own application.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) class.

To avoid crashes, use an outer catch block - sometimes the System.Diagnostics classes cause operating system level exceptions that I usually want to ignore in the case of a small scale utility app.